# Pass parameters withing Datasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need help passing a parameter to the DataSource `BindCompanyCharItems()` to filter records, which I bind to a `CheckList` called `chklstCompCharItems`.

The parameter I am trying to use is `<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="CompCharID" />`

My GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid_Data" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="CompCharID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Comp Char Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Invite Permission">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstCompCharItems" DataSource='<%# BindCompanyCharItems()%>' DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind ("Id") %>'  runat="server">
             </asp:CheckBoxList>  
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
DataSource='<%# BindCompanyCharItems((Eval("Id")))%>'
```

Your "BindCompanyCharItems()" must accept parameter and you should then use this parameter to filter.